# Where is IsolatedStorage located on the filesystem when using IIS/ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, isolatedstorage

For one reason or another, I'm using IsolatedStorage with ASP.Net under IIS 8.0(Integrated mode w/ .Net 4.5). This actually works exactly as I'd expect. However, it's very handy to debug isolated storage by looking at the files it creates on your filesystem. I can't find these files.

My setup is so that I have a AppPool named `TestPool`. It has an identity of `Jordan` (my local user account). The applications seems to work perfectly with data persisting and such. I just can't find where it's actually stored on the file system

Where is is Isolated Storage stored in the filesystem when using it from ASP.Net with IIS?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, IIS has some really **weird** behavior when you set the app pool identity to a user in the administrator group. If you're using a regular user, it'll be something like

```
C:\Users\FooBar\AppData\Local\IsolatedStorage
```

When you're using an administrator as the identity though, it apparently bumps IIS up so that it thinks it's running as SYSTEM or some such. The path it uses for IsolatedStorage in this case is

```
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\IsolatedStorage
```

Although I've not tested it, I assume this could probably lead to some crazy behavior where if you had two app pools set as administrator accounts on the same machine, they'd both see the same instance of IsolatedStorage, where it'd be expected to be different. Either way though, IIS writing to `C:\Windows\System32` is plenty scary as it is. I'm only doing this for ease of debugging, so it's not a huge thing for me to worry about at least