# How to Create a file from database and uploading it to the server in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I have a scenario like create a file from database table data and uploading it to the server. i written a code for this it's working fine locally after hosted this application in IIS it's giving error like this .

> *Access to the path 'C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile' is denied.' Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the
>   execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error and where it originated in the
>   code.  Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access
>   to the path 'C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile' is denied. 
>   ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider
>   granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request
>   identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically
>   {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6 and IIS 7, and
>   the configured application pool identity on IIS 7.5) that is used if
>   the application is not impersonating. If the application is
>   impersonating via , the identity will be
>   the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated
>   request user.  To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file
>   in File Explorer, choose "Properties" and select the Security tab.
>   Click "Add" to add the appropriate user or group. Highlight the
>   ASP.NET account, and check the boxes for the desired access.*

Can any one please help me how to resolve this error.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? It [sounds like you are talking to the "user" directory](http://superuser.com/questions/598601/what-is-system32-config-systemprofile) (AppData, etc) on the web-server; if so... why? what are you trying to do in there, that you couldn't do just as easily in a temp file in the temp directory?

Comment: @MarcGravell   i'm using the following code but it still giving the same error after hosting in IIS  ` string path = Path.GetTempPath();
            path=Path.Combine(path, "file.tsv");`

Comment: as per http://stackoverflow.com/q/16679571/23354, it sounds like you're simply using an IIS app-pool identity that is in the administrator group; if that is correct, then simply: *don't do that*.

Comment: Simple guess, your app_pool identity's Temp path isn't set thus defaulting to `c:\windows\system32`. Have you tried to write in a local folder (app_data or so) ?

Comment: @xum59 i was able to write a file in that path but while uploading it giving the above mentioned error..

Comment: "in that path" : Path.GetTempPath() or .\App_Data ? While debugging locally or already hosted ? As @Marc mentionned, you shouldn't be able nor wanting to write in system32.

Comment: @Muralikrishna you keep saying "but while uploading"; where are you uploading to here? You *are* the server at this point...

Answer (score 0):

Check IIS_User permissions to provided address. One non secure way is to give all permissions to every one. but be aware this is non secure way. try to manage IIS_User permissions using yourFolder/Properties/Security tab